# Is an unquoted charset valid?

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags, quotes

I was checking out the new [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and noticed that the default HTML included: `<meta charset=utf-8 />`. Notice how the encoding `utf-8` is unquoted. I wanted to know if this is just a mistake or valid HTML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value doesn't contain any of the character that would require the value to be quoted. It is valid.

Comment: Are there then any reasons not to have the charset unquoted (i.e. previous browsers not recognizing it?).